# What does !r do in str() and repr()?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, formatting, repr

According to the [Python 2.7.12 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

> `!s` (apply `str()`) and `!r` (apply `repr()`) can be used to convert
>   the value before it is formatted.
>
> ```
> >>> import math
> >>> print 'The value of PI is approximately {}.'.format(math.pi)
> The value of PI is approximately 3.14159265359.
> >>> print 'The value of PI is approximately {!r}.'.format(math.pi)
> The value of PI is approximately 3.141592653589793.
> ```

Interestingly, the converted value is the output of `repr()`, rather than `str()`.

```
>>> str(math.pi)
'3.14159265359'
>>> repr(math.pi)
'3.141592653589793'
```

So what does "convert the value" mean here? Making it less human-readable?

Comment: It is interesting to observe different precision for `str(..)` and `repr(..)` though

Answer (score 101, accepted):

In order to format something *in* a string, a string representation of that something must first be created.  "convert the value" is basically talking about how the string representation is to be constructed.  In python, there are two fairly natural choices to get a string representation of something ... `str` and `repr`.  `str` is generally a little more human friendly, `repr` is generally more precise.  Perhaps the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) is the best place to go looking for the difference:

> `object.__repr__(self)`
>
> - Called by the `repr()` built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.
> - This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.
>
> `object.__str__(self)`
>
> - Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.
> - This method differs from `object.__repr__()` in that there is no expectation that `__str__()` return a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation can be used.
> - The default implementation defined by the built-in type object calls `object.__repr__()`.

In `str.format`, `!s` chooses to use `str` to format the object whereas `!r` chooses `repr` to format the value.

The difference can easily be seen with strings (as `repr` for a string will include outer quotes).:

```
>>> 'foo {}'.format('bar')
'foo bar'
>>> 'foo {!r}'.format('bar')
"foo 'bar'"
```

What the difference between these two methods really depends critically on the objects being formatted.  For many objects (e.g. those that don't override the `__str__` method), there will be no difference in the formatted output.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit, use `repr` instead of `!r`.

Comment: @mehmet. `!r` is pretty explicit too. It's like saying you should use `a = a + 1` instead of `a += 1` just because someone is unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's like saying you should use `a = a + 1` instead of `a += 1` *in a world where only Python has the `+=` operator shorthand*. I agree that using `!r` is perfectly fine, but it's not entirely equivalent because *even a developer who has never seen Python has probably seen `+=`*.

Comment: @mehmet The point is that we can create a string that carries its formating instructions with it. You can do `my_format = "{0!r}` but you can't do `my_format = "{repr(0)}". If we want to pass the format strings around, we need the former syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone, after reading those 2 answers here, is still wondering what to use `!r` or `repr` for, I'd like to shed some light on my own observation of our huge corporate shared library:

After scanning the usage of `!r` and `repr` in fstrings, I FOUND that 50% are with `repr` and 50% are with `!r`.

After looking at the blame on git, I found that people with `!r` contribution are somehow more passionate about programming than others with `repr`.

It is most likely that people who use repr() have not read the documentation of fstring (https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#s-r-and-a-are-redundant), which allows `!r` as a short convenience. The repulsive word "redundant" from pep-049 gives the false impression that it is something to be avoided.

Answer (score -3):

I called the str(object) and the function -format() and print() to compute the as someone called it “informal”.

To perfectly print string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of `!r` and `!s` in `str.format`. Also, please [edit] to provide details of what you mean by "informal".