# print(f"He said his name is {name!r}")

Tags: python, string

The code has an exclamation mark in the third line.  The variable was not define with it "!r". Why is running or executing?

```
name = 'Fred'
print(f"He said his name is {name}.")

print(f"He said his name is {name!r}")  # this line*


My_name_is = 'I said my name is Parker'
print(f'what did you say? {My_name_is!r}.')
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418070/what-does-r-do-in-str-and-repr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does !r do in str() and repr()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418070/what-does-r-do-in-str-and-repr)