# what is the use of {!r}' in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Python3 beginner doubts.

I was going through a wonderful document https://pymotw.com/3/argparse/index.html#module-argparse

```
results = parser.parse_args()
print('simple_value     = {!r}'.format(results.simple_value))
print('constant_value   = {!r}'.format(results.constant_value))
```

first time, noticing this `{!r}'`. I don't know what to call this or search for in google.

Could someone break this for an easy understanding?

Comment: Google generally has results if you type out the symbols in words. For example, I searched for "python exclamation mark r". It's a bit counter-intuitive, since the symbols themselves tend to have special meanings.

Comment: see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418070/what-does-r-do-in-str-and-repr

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings is the primary doc for the `str.format` syntax.